# Css of both themes of my child theme isn't showing up!

Tags: themes

I made a child theme of a child called one-edge. One edge is a child theme of the theme llorix-one-lite. in the one-edge child theme folder I put a style.css and a functions.php. in the style.css I am linking to the parent template: llorix-one-lite.

In the functions.php I placed the following code:

```
<?php
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
    function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    }
?>
```

The problem is that when I inspect the code of my website it only shows the css of the parent theme: llorix-one-lite.

Should i just put both theme names in the style.css like this to make them both show up?:

Template: llorix-one-lite, one-edge?

thank you guys

Answer (score 2):

Child themes of child themes (aka grandchild themes) are not supported, so this will not work:

```
Template: llorix-one-lite, one-edge
```

Instead, I'd suggest forking the llorix-one-lite theme into One Edge and proceeding from there.